# I want to update list object values using http PATCH request in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

I have the following rest API JSON server data.

```
"User": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "username": "ABC",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"
      "business": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "businessName": "my business1"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "businessName": "my business2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to update the "business" object first-row value of "businessName" to "ABC business" using PATCH request.
How I can do that?

here is my code:

**MyModel.dart**

```
class MyModel{
  int id;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  List<BusinessModel> business;

  EnterpriseModel({
    required this.id,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.business,
  });
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['username'] = this.username;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['business'] = this.business!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}
```

**BusinessModel.dart**

```
class BusinessModel{
  int id;
  String? businessName;

  EnterpriseModel({
    required this.id,
    this.businessName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['businessName'] = this.businessName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void buttonClick(){
  updateUserDetails(
    MyModel(
     id: 0,
     BusinessModel(
       id: 0,
       businessName: 'ABC business'
     )
    )
  )
}

Future<MyModel?> updateUserDetails(MyModel m) async{

  final String apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/user/0';

  final http.Response response = 
    await http.patch(Uri.parse(apiUrl),
    body: json.encode(m.toJson()));
  print(response.body);

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

the following output removes the second row from JSON data

```
{
 "id": 0,
 "username": "ABC",
 "email": "abc@gmail.com"
 "business": [
   {
     "id": 0,
     "businessName": "ABC business"
   }
  ]
}
```

my server detail:
https://medium.com/@devmrin/create-a-rest-api-json-server-in-less-than-1-minute-acf286600f03

Comment: What have you tried? This question is kinda broad and involves multiple steps. E.g. JSON decoding, JSON encoding and creating the HTTP PATCH request itself. Do you need help with all of these steps or do you have a more specific problem with one of the steps?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. What is the problem you have?

Comment: I want to update the "ABC" user business detail.
e.g: businessName from "my business1" to  "ABC business"

Comment: Does the server respond to /user/0/business/0 ? This is really a server question; what URI to use to modify data below the top level. Once you know that, experiment in Postman.